# Should I flag mildly negative comments that hint at an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I've decided against linking to the specific question (and answers) because I don't want to just stir up trouble, but...

I recently came across a relatively well-written and well-received question (at the time of writing, it had a score of 12 and 6 favorites). In the comments, a user said something like "All you have to do is XYZ" (without any detail).

I saw a different approach to solving the problem, so I put together an answer. My answer has a positive score, but also a reasonable comment from the original asker saying that he'd prefer not to solve the issue using my strategy. The commenter from the OP also left a comment on my answer saying "the easiest solution is XYZ" and another one saying "I can't believe the workarounds I'm seeing to avoid XYZ".

Another user posted a second answer. This same commenter left yet another "the easiest solution is XYZ" comment plus a second comment saying that this answer was from "the stone age".

It seems to me that (a) this commenter should actually write a full answer if they feel so strongly about their solution, and (b) this commenter should be nicer to other users in general. What is the correct course of action to take here? Any one of these comments on their own wouldn't really jump out to me as anything exceptional, but taken together it feels like mild bullying. Does all this add up to enough for a "moderator intervention" flag?

Comment: In this edge case, yes, certainly, that user is essentially harassing other users. I'd use a custom mod flag so you can explain what's going on. but just 1 comment, no.

Comment: I found the post in question. Yes, the user in question is acting a little arrogant, but not yet to the extent that it'd require moderator intervention. It's coming over as an overconfident backseat driver, the OP is rightly calling their bluff by suggesting they post an answer. Still, flagging the question with a custom flag and asking moderators to have a look won't hurt.

Comment: @MartijnPieters should I just have linked directly to it in my question? I wasn't sure about proper etiquette here.

Comment: @BenP.: No, no need to draw in the mob. You gave enough of a description for a determined community member to find the post without those that are just disinterested enough to vote on anything in sight to not bother. :-)

Comment: Well, sometimes it's actually necessary to deal with _"stone age"_ technologies, that's part of my job sometimes. Nevertheless advising beginners to start out with such tools (e.g. [turbo-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/turbo-c%2b%2b/info) nowadays is kind of abusive.